# This is the first time I have a laptop with dedicated GPU, I am facing few issues

Tags: 20.04, 64-bit, gpu, nvidia-settings

I have logged the 'gpu-manager.log' from '/var/log' directory. I have this shown

'''

```
log_file: /var/log/gpu-manager.log
last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-was-loaded file
can't access /opt/amdgpu-pro/bin/amdgpu-pro-px
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.14.1-051401-generic/kernel
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.14.1-051401-generic/updates/dkms
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/5.14.1-051401-generic/kernel
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/5.14.1-051401-generic/updates/dkms
Is nvidia loaded? no
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? no
Is intel loaded? no
Is radeon loaded? no
Is radeon blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu loaded? yes
Is amdgpu blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu versioned? no
Is amdgpu pro stack? no
Is nouveau loaded? no
Is nouveau blacklisted? yes
Is nvidia kernel module available? no
Is amdgpu kernel module available? no
Vendor/Device Id: 1002:1638
BusID "PCI:5@0:0:0"
Is boot vga? yes
Vendor/Device Id: 10de:2560
BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
Is boot vga? no
Error: can't access /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/driver
The device is not bound to any driver.
/etc/u-d-c-nvidia-runtimepm-override found. Will try runtimepm if the kernel supports it.
Linux 5.14 detected.
Is nvidia runtime pm supported for "0x2560"? yes
Trying to create new file: /run/nvidia_runtimepm_supported
Checking power status in /proc/driver/nvidia/gpus/0000:01:00.0/power
Error while opening /proc/driver/nvidia/gpus/0000:01:00.0/power
Is nvidia runtime pm enabled for "0x2560"? no
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Does it require offloading? no
last cards number = 2
Has amd? yes
Has intel? no
Has nvidia? yes
How many cards? 2
Has the system changed? No
AMD IGP detected
Desktop system detected
or laptop with open drivers
Nothing to do
```

'''
I do not know how this is affecting my system, but I do believe there are problems. Please help me out.

Comment: What problems?... Have you disabled Secure Boot? It's convenient to do that if you're using Nvidia's drivers.

Comment: I have disabled the secure boot. I don't know how to install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: If you selected the option to install 3rd party drivers, firmware, etc. when you installed Ubuntu -and- ypu disabled Secure Boot then there's nothing left to do. If you didn't select that option you can install then now easily with Additional Drivers (Software & Updates > Additional Drivers tab). Just select and apply the recommended version, reboot, done.